# Angular error: Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schem

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, rxjs

I'm having this error using angular 7, just started today and idk really what's going on here.

I tried update, remove and install all packages again, but no luck.

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
> configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - configuration.entry should be one of these:    function | object { : non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string |
>   [non-empty string]    -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
>   Details:
>
>   - configuration.entry should be an instance of function
>     -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
>   - configuration.entry['styles'] should be a string.
>     -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item 'C:/node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\scss\mdb-free.scss'
>     twice.
>   - configuration.entry should be a string.
>     -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration.entry should be an array:
>     [non-empty string] WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a
>     configuration object that does not match the API schema.
> - configuration.entry should be one of these:    function | object { : non-empty string | [non-empty string] } | non-empty string |
>   [non-empty string]    -> The entry point(s) of the compilation.
>   Details:
>
>   - configuration.entry should be an instance of function
>     -> A Function returning an entry object, an entry string, an entry array or a promise to these things.
>   - configuration.entry['styles'] should be a string.
>     -> The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item 'C:/node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\scss\mdb-free.scss'
>     twice.
>   - configuration.entry should be a string.
>     -> An entry point without name. The string is resolved to a module which is loaded upon startup.
>   - configuration.entry should be an array:
>     [non-empty string]
>     at webpack (C:/node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:31:9)
>     at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (C:/node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:37:37)
>     at Observable._trySubscribe
>     (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
>     at Observable.subscribe (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
>     at C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
>     at Object.subscribeToResult (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:10:45)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:82:29)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:76:14)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>     at TapSubscriber._next (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:65:26)
>     at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
>     at InnerSubscriber._next (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
>     at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:/node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)

Comment: Please check/review the section "styles" in your "angular.json" file. You probably have some problem in this section, like duplicated files, files that do not exist, filenames without quotation, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solutions was reinstall node and create a new angular project.

Comment: This is not a solution. It is defeat

Comment: kindly don't comment out if you don't know what's wrong with this error specifically

right answer is from @Bereket Gebremeskel that we need to recheck if duplicate entry of a package is included

Answer (score 18):

Check your angular.json file , if there is a duplicate CSS file! sometimes when you install dependencies, they will add CSS file that already existed in the angular.json file.

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to run an ionic project using `ionic cap run ios` and got this message including `configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item {...path/to/item} twice`. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me recently in an Angular Visual Studio 2019 project that already had bootstrap, after installing ngx-bootstrap.  Searching further down into the error I found:

**Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item '...\source\repos...\ClientApp\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' twice.**

And in **angular.json** I had:

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

I was able to fix this by removing one of the duplicate bootstrap entries:

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

And Then my project was running again.  The key here was to check the error message for what is wrong in the configuration, if specified.

As an example, in the original post we see the very similar:

- configuration.entry['styles'] should not contain the item 'C:\Users\smoreira\Documents\projetos\oficiais\doc-translator-front\node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\scss\mdb-free.scss' twice.

Comment: the best answer than reinstall node and create a new project.

Answer (score 3):

Installing the newest version of webpack worked for me, version 4.29.6 with angular 7.2.11

Comment: This worked for me too.  I updated from Angular 6.1 to 7, following the guide in the Angular docs.  After following the required steps I received the error above.  I ended up running 'ng update webpack' which updated webpack to 4.30.0.  My project then built.

Answer (score 0):

As error is saying

> node_modules\angular-bootstrap-md\scss\mdb-free.scss' twice

It means the same style has repeated twice inside you `"styles":` tag so you need to remove one. Check this in your `angular.json` file.